# Task Scheduler not running task when set to run whether logged in or not

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to set a task to run hourly to record results of a program I have designed. Now when I open the task scheduler and set the program path to C:\destination\path\data.py, at a scheduled time, and to run only when I am logged on, it runs perfectly.

When I set it up exactly the same, but now I set the run if user is logged on or not, then the program doesn't run at all, whether I am logged on or off. It asks for the administrator password, I enter it and everything is accepted, but still nothing happens.

This seems to be an issue a lot of people are having but I am yet to find a definitive solution to this problem. I have even tried to contact Microsoft Support and they just send me in circles. Can anyone assist with this?

Comment: The only way it can run regardless of whether the user is logged on or off is by using session 0, the session that's isolated for non-interactive services and tasks, with the user logged on as a service-for-user (S4U) logon. The task can fail in this case if it requires an interactive session, or possibly if it needs network credentials or access to mapped network drives that aren't available.

Comment: To rule out a problem with file associations, change the task to run "python.exe", using its fully-qualified path, and set "C:\destination\path\data.py" as the argument.

Comment: See [Help! My Scheduled Task does not run…](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2015/02/18/help-my-scheduled-task-does-not-run/)